# exec vscode not redirecting output to /dev/null

Tags: bash, io-redirection, exec

I have the following bash script:

```
exec '/mnt/c/Users/WindowsUserName/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe' $@ &>/dev/null &
```

When I run the script I get

```
➜  ~ ./code foo.js
➜  ~
[main 2021-11-18T17:54:12.206Z] update#setState idle
[main 2021-11-18T17:54:42.215Z] update#setState checking for updates
[main 2021-11-18T17:54:42.435Z] update#setState idle
```

^ The output is not being redirected to `/dev/null`. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Not directly an answer but double quote the variable `"$@"` as you use it. Otherwise it won't work right

Answer (score 0):

Usually `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` point to the terminal. This reference is destroyed by `&>/dev/null` (except for `stdin`). But these references are not the only way of a process to write to the terminal.

```
ctty=$(awk '{ print $7}' /proc/self/stat)
echo "controlling tty: $(( (ctty>>8) & 255 )):$(( (ctty>>20) + (ctty&255) ))"
```

A process can open its controlling terminal and write directly to it. This can be prevented with `nohup`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm not really sure what to do with this information however.  How do I redirect the output to /dev/null after the reference has been destroyed?

Comment: @KevinKoehler You don't. It's not even possible. You have to take away the controlling terminal i.e. remove the process from the session. Quoting my answer: "This can be prevented with nohup"

Answer (score -1):

The `&` before the redirect detaches the `exec` command from the console. As it is right now, you're detaching the `exec` command, then creating an empty command which is redirected to `/dev/null` and detaching that. I believe that you want to remove the `&` before the `>/dev/null` and leave the other one so the command gets properly redirected and detached.

Comment: `&>/dev/null` is short for `>/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Learn something new every day. Sorry about that.